# Multiple conditional in Laravel Middleware

Tags: laravel

I have a middleware like this:

```
class HasBilling {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

       $user_profile = UsersProfile::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

        if (!is_object($user_profile) && !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('soy-agente') && !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('soy-agente_inversor')) {
            return redirect()->route('myaccount.facturacion.ver')->with('error', 'No posees datos de facturación. Antes de usar algunas funciones como facturación, publicidad, merkado, tarifas... debes rellenar los datos.');
        }

        if(is_object($user_profile) && is_null($user_profile->validate)){
            return redirect()->route('myaccount.facturacion.ver')->with('error', 'Tus datos de facturación están pendiente de validar'); 
        }

        if(is_object($user_profile) && $user_profile->validate == 2){
            return redirect()->route('myaccount.facturacion.ver')->with('error', 'Tus datos de facturación han sido rechazados.');
       
        }


        if(!is_null(\Auth::user()->activity) && \Auth::user()->activity == "empresa"){
            $autorizado = UsersProfileAutorizado::find($user_profile->id);

            if(!is_object($autorizado)){
                return redirect()->route('myaccount.autorizado.ver')->with('error', 'No posees ningún autorizado. Al ser una empresa, antes de usar algunas funciones como la facturación o la publicidad debes rellenar los datos de autorizado.');
            }

            if(is_object($autorizado) && is_null($autorizado->validate)){
                return redirect()->route('myaccount.autorizado.ver')->with('error', 'Tu autorizado está pendiente de validar.');
            }

            if(is_object($autorizado) && $autorizado->validate == 2){
                return redirect()->route('myaccount.autorizado.ver')->with('error', 'Tu autorizado ha sido rechazado.');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

The problem with this is that it checks the first IF, but the others are omitted.

The middleware works because the first if always checks for it, but the rest "ignore" them.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the errors in an array, and redirect at the end of the method.

```php
class HasBilling {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

       $errors = [];

       $user_profile = UsersProfile::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

        if (
            !is_object($user_profile) 
            && !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('soy-agente') 
            && !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('soy-agente_inversor')
        ) {
            $errors[] = 'No posees datos de facturación. Antes de usar algunas funciones como facturación, publicidad, merkado, tarifas... debes rellenar los datos.';
        }

        if (
            is_object($user_profile) 
            && is_null($user_profile->validate)
        ){
            $errors[] = 'Tus datos de facturación están pendiente de validar'); 
        }

        // Add other checks where you can append $errors array

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            return redirect()
                ->route('myaccount.facturacion.ver')
                ->with('errors', $errors); 
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

When reading the errors in the `'myaccount.autorizado.ver` route, you have to make sure to read, parse and show the `$errors` array instead of the single error. For example in a `foreach` that shows a list of errors.